# Cytoscape.js arbor layout canvas renderer?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I searched here and found a reference to their being a canvas renderer, but have not found it as an option.  Has that project been completed?

I am trying to render 200-300 nodes and roughly 600-1000 edges and am not seeing acceptable performance.  I had initially been using sigma.js and was happy with the rendering, but the lack of documentation and small feature set pushed to use cytoscape.js...which I am loving for how easy it is to work with the styles and accessing node and edge attributes...

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered elsewhere, but I will reiterate for completeness.  Please do not ask in more than one place in future.  It will not make for faster answers, and it's confusing for others.

There is indeed a canvas renderer, and it is the only renderer available to you -- other than the trivial null renderer or a renderer you write yourself.

As for performance, it is a function of the layout performance and you're using one of the most expensive types of layouts -- forcedirected -- although nice for several graphs.  If you want better performance given the size of your graph, you're better off using a nonsimulation layout, like the breadthfirst layout.

You also have the option of writing your own layout that could be completely tailoured to your dataset.  It's very easy with the API:  http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#extensions/layouts